# How to echo html with variables in herf?

Tags: php, html, string

I tried to echo the following html, I can see from firebug that the variables are correctly printed, but it doesn't show up on the webpage. Would anyone please help me correct this?

```
$html ="<p><a rel='friends' href='$domain/$dir/$tag/$version/' target='_blank' $img></a></p>";
```

Comment: What are the values of the variables? What is the HTML source that gets generated? How does it differ from the HTML source you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing between the  and the  tags. you need something like this:

```
<p><a rel='friends' href='$domain/$dir/$tag/$version/' target='_blank'> $img </a></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your $img is in the wrong spot:

```
$html ="<p><a rel='friends' href='$domain/$dir/$tag/$version/' target='_blank'>$img</a></p>";
```

Then again I think you want to do this:

```
$html ="<p><a rel='friends' href='$domain/$dir/$tag/$version/' target='_blank'><img src='$img' /></a></p>";
```